# Adding title bar to JFrame (Linux)

Tags: java, linux, swing, netbeans, titlebar

I am trying to add a title bar with the "X" button to an application. I've read about Look&Feel in Java, but I have no idea what I am missing (I just created a Desktop Application, added a JFrame Form, and dragged'n'dropped a table - no logic yet).

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication14;

import framez.NewJFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author uluroki
 */
public class JavaApplication14 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            NewJFrame myframe = new NewJFrame();                
            myframe.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
  }
}


/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/*
 * NewJFrame.java
 *
 * Created on 2012-01-11, 21:13:30
 */
package framez;

/**
 *
 * @author uluroki
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form NewJFrame */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 375, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

This is what NetBeans generated.

Comment: Please include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org). By default, a `JFrame` instance will have a title bar, unless [`setUndecorated(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29) is invoked prior to *realization*.

Comment: hmmm Native OS rellated issue e.g. http://www.pendrivelinux.com/ubuntu-desktop-effects-fixing-the-missing-titlebar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I just created a Desktop Application, added a JFrame Form, 
and dragged'n'dropped some buttons - no logic yet
```

there are these Standard [Top-Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

`JFrame`  --> have got three buttons Minimize, Maximize and Close

`JDialog` --> has only one button Close

`JWindow` --> is un_decorated by default, haven't any buttons

basically there aren't any changes for numbers of button (for `Top-Level Containers`) by using/changing another [Look & Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)